# Computation of a double integral.

Tags: real-analysis

1. Compute the double integral $$\int_{(0,\infty)}\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{1}{(1+y)(1+yx^2)}d\lambda_2(x,y)$$
2. Deduce that $$\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-1}d\lambda_1(x) =\frac{\pi^2}{4}.$$

Hint: Observe that $\frac{1}{(1+y)(1+yx^2)}=\frac{1}{x^2-1}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+xy^2}-\frac{1}{1+y}\right)$

3. Show that $$\int_{(0,1)}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-1}d\lambda_1(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

I was able to do 1.and 2. but I've been stuck on 3. for quite some time now. I asked the assistant and he told me to do a change of variable $y=\frac{1}{x}$. I did that and got $$\int_{(0,1)}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-1}d\lambda_1(x)=\int_{(1,\infty)}\frac{\ln(y)}{y^2-1}d\lambda_1(y).$$
I really dont see how that is supposed to help me to see why the result is $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$. Could somebody please elaborate?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $\lambda_{2}{\left(x,y\right)}$. Do you simply mean $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$?

Comment: The lamda indicates the lebesgue measure and as the integrand is nonnegative within $(0,\infty)$ Tonelli's thm allows us to interpret $d\lambda(x,y)$ simply is $dxdy$. (I might be wrong, but thats the way I interpret it).

Comment: So can we say this?
$$
I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx  = \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx
$$
so we can add the integrals
$$
2I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx  + \int_1^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx  = \frac{\pi^2}{4}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\pi^2}{4}=\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-1}d\lambda_1(x)=2\int_{(0,1)}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-1}d\lambda_1(x)$$

Therefore, $$\int_{(0,1)}\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-1}d\lambda_1(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$